# How can I clone EMR cluster using MWAA Airflow dag

Tags: amazon-emr, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I wanted to clone the pre-existing cluster / previous terminated cluster from the EMR side.

However, I would like to achieve this using airflow dag from MWAA env instead of doing it manually.

Currently, I am able to connect to Spark using `EmrAddStepsOperator`  but is there any other ways we can clone a cluster from `EmrCreateJobFlowOperator` using `JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES` parameters?  All the examples I have found are simply creating a new cluster but not cloning one.

The reason for asking this is because the security team does not want me to have the IAM Role to create but only to clone.